# Como criar instalação de projeto feito no android estudio

Tags: android, android-studio

Criei um projeto no Andoid Studio, executo ele na máquina virtual certinho, agora gostaria de "compilar" ele para instalar em um celular de verdade.

Como faço isso? Eu crio um arquivo e passo para o celular? Tenho que colocar no Google Play?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você provavelmente está utilizando uma ferramenta de build para cuidar do seu projeto. Por você estar usando o AST, eu presumo que você está utilizando o `gradle` como sua ferramenta de build.

Então vamos por partes pra entender um pouco mais.

### Overview sobre o build tool

O sistema de build do Android é o kit de ferramentas que você usa para construir, testar, executar e empacotar seus apps. O sistema de build pode ser executado como uma ferramenta integrada no menu Android Studio e independentemente da linha de comando. Você pode usar os recursos do sistema de compilação para:

- Personalizar, configurar e estender o processo de build.
- Criar múltiplas APKs para seu aplicativo com características diferentes, usando o mesmo projeto e módulos.
- A reutilização de código e recursos entre conjuntos de origem.

### Uma olhada mais a fundo sobre como funciona o build

O processo de build envolve muitos processos que geram arquivos intermediários no caminho para a produção de um .apk. Se você estiver desenvolvendo no Android Studio, o processo de build completo é feito a cada vez que você executar a task `gradle build` para o seu projeto ou módulos. O processo de build é muito flexível, por isso é útil, no entanto, para entender é necessário saber o que está acontecendo sob todo o processo de compilação, e ver como é configurável e extensível. O diagrama a seguir descreve as diferentes ferramentas e processos que estão envolvidos em uma compilação:
[image]

A ferramenta de build mescla todos os recursos configurados, tipos de compilação e as dependências.

### Output do Build

A compilação gera um APK para cada variante de build na pasta `app/build`: o diretório `app/build/outputs/apk/` contém pacotes chamados `app--.apk`; por exemplo, app-full-release.apk e app-demo-debug.apk.

Essa é a sua .apk para rodar em um device e testar.

Comment: C:\Users\Silvio\AndroidStudioProjects\MeuProjeto\app\build\outputs, é nessa sequencia de pastas que deveria estar o .apk? não tem a pasta app, devo fazer algo para aparecer? O gradle faz o build quando inicia o studio, mas não cria o arquivo.

Comment: "não tem a pasta app" quis dizer: não tem a pasta apk.

Comment: Você tem o Gradle instalado na sua maquina?

Comment: Tenho sim, ele faz o build, consegui encontrar os arquivos depois que "startei" a maquina virtual, só que não tem o mesmo nome que você colocou, estão com os seguintes nomes: "app-debug" e "app-debug-unaligned". Estão certos? esses já podem ser instalados? ou preciso fazer o definitivo?

Comment: O app-debug.apk é o default quando você não sobrescreve na seção de buildTypes. Mas sim, é só você jogar esse .apk para o seu celular e instalar lá. O Android Studio tem uma opção também de você subir o projeto ao dar run e conectar seu device na sua maquina, assim fica um processo automático, sem você precisar manualmente mandar o .apk pro device.

Answer (score 0):

Não, você não precisa colocar ele na Play Store. Apenas faça o seguinte:

Pegue no celular que você gostaria de instalar e active a opção de depuração por USB (USB debug) que geralmente você encontra em Definições > Opções de programador.
Tendo activado essa opção no seu celular, conecta o celular usando um cabo USB e depois, no Android Studio, quando você clicar em Run, o seu celular aparecerá na lista, daí é só selecioná-lo e aguardar o fim do processo!

Espero ter ajudado!